# Can I Setup a localhost virtual host on google analitcs

Tags: google-analytics

I have a virtual host, say,  `http.mylocalhost.com` on my localhost. I want to use `google analytics`. Can I create project with my this virtual host on google analytics and it starts working of tracking the visits and every thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a public facing address associated with a web server that can be reached, then yes, you can put their validation code inside your header or the html file in your directory and it will validate it and you are good to go. But if not, then I don't see how you would get the data sent for aggregation or analysis.